# Prevent UISearchBar from Hiding when scrolling in UITableView (Keep UISearchBar shown when scrolling) - Swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I currently have a UISearchBar (code below) which works fine however I'm trying to make it so upon scrolling in my UITableView, my UISearchBar does not disappear. One of the things I've read is to embed a searchController into a view controller with the following line of code: `navigationItem.searchController = yourSearchController` and then to prevent the UISearchBar from hiding, add this line of code: `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false` however it has not worked. I've also read to put the SearchBar above the UITableView in the View Hierarchy, but when I do that and place it below the Navigation Bar, upon scrolling it overlaps the tableView cells. Do I need a SearchController, and if so, how do I implement this? I've spent hours searching through similar StackOverflow threads with the same question asked many years ago and have attempted to implement the responses, however, none of the responses have worked. Any response would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

UISearchBar IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

viewDidLoad Func:

```
filteredData = data
```

UISearchBar Code:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
   if searchText.isEmpty {
      filteredData = data
   } else {
      filteredData = data.filter{$0.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
   }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

View Hierarchy:

[image]

View Controller Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a UISearchController as a variable:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

and then on viewDidLoad

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

The difference here is that your seachBar is embedded on the title of the navigationItem, so it won't disappear on scrolling. This shows the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. What this has done, is it has created a searchBar at the top of the screen above the Navigation Bar. However, when you search in it, the screen goes black. Is there any way to embed a UISearchController into my existing searchBar?

Comment: You have to conform to the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol, and implement the updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController). Don't forget on viewDidLoad to do searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.definesPresentationContext = true